# How to get back pattern lock with Exchange/ActiveSync account?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, lock-screens, exchange, active-sync

I have added an Exchange/ActiveSync email account to my Android phone. This required me to set the email application as a device administrator so that ActiveSync can control certain features of my phone.
One of the controlled features is the way I can unlock my phone (from the lockscreen). Exchange seems to limit me to the "PIN" and "Password" options. But I prefer to use a pattern lock.

Please note that I have administrative access to the domain in which the Exchange server is running and I would like to control this behaviour from the server side. I do NOT want to circumvent restrictions on my device.

I have already created a new ActiveSync profile (which doesn't enforce any password restrictions) for my user account, but it doesn't seem to affect the issue. It seems like ActiveSync in general restricts me to a password/PIN unlock and the profile can just control the complexity rules for those.

I realize this isn't really an Android issue, but I assumed this would be the best place to ask.

---

**Update**: Please note that this seems to be a new feature introduced with Android 4.0 (Ice Cream Sandwich). When I was using Android 2.3, I was able to use pattern lock just fine.

Comment: I have an exchange account on my device, and I can use pattern lock. If you remove the exchange account, it lets you use pattern lock?

Comment: @RyanConrad Yes. This only started happening after I flashed ICS on the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to get this to work was for us to do the following in our Exchange server.

1. Create a new **Exchange ActiveSync Mailbox Policy** in the **Client Access Organization Configuration**.
2. Make sure that **Require password** is disabled for the policy.

   [image]
3. Go to the mailbox of the user in question, in the **Recipient Configuration** and open the **Properties** for the mailbox. In the **Mailbox Features** tab, select **Exchange ActiveSync** and open the **Properties**.

   Select your newly created **ActiveSync Mailbox Policy** and confirm your selection.

   [image]
4. You might need to remove and re-add the the account on your phone to make sure that it no longer asks you to set a password.

Answer (score 1):

My work account limits me from using pattern lock. The way I get around it is by using Swype and a password that is a real word, that way you Swype the pattern of the word to unlock your phone.

Get Swype from beta.Swype.com.